# Upper limit of gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, celestial-mechanics, escape-velocity

Now I don't mean maximum gravity because there is no maximum gravity. What I mean is what is the escape distance? In other words, how far would I have to be from a mass to get away from its gravity? It can't be the Roche limit since that is density dependent instead of mass dependent. Now the only mass it is dependent on is the primary mass(so dwarf planet, asteroid, moon, etc.) up to a point. It can't be where the atmosphere ends since the moon has too thin of an atmosphere and Pluto's atmosphere periodically freezes onto the surface of the planet.

So how could I figure out the escape distance from any significant mass(even an asteroid would do here) given these parameters:

Mass

Radius

Surface gravity

and

Density

Comment: Infinity. Calculate what it takes to go to infinity. It'll be a finite number because the force decreases as you go further away.

Comment: This is a little bit a philosophical question. The answer depends from the the point of view about are there unique particles (gravitons) or not. If one believes that graviton exist and that gravitons are unique (elementary particles) then gravity far away from matter has to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a simple answer to this because the gravitational field of any mass extends out to an infinite distance. If you had just a single mass in the universe then there is no distance at which the gravity becomes zero.

However the universe contains lots of masses, so in practice there is a distance at which the gravitational field becomes swamped by the gravitational fields of other objects. There are various ways of describing this, of which the most commonly used in systems like the Solar system are the [gravitational sphere of influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_(astrodynamics)) (SOI) and the [Hill sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere). You don't say exactly what you are trying to do, but it sounds like the sphere of influence would be more appropriate for you.

When you go to really massive objects the distances involved can be remarkably large. For example the gravitational field of the [great attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Attractor) is important over distances of hundreds of millions of light years.